# Unity crashes on my PC and I don't know why

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was doing a course for learning the platform Unity and how I can make video games, etc..

I have installed the program in my PC, and the installation was correct, but at the time for starting the program, it doesn't end to start and windows told me, "The program stopped working, close it" and always the same.

Someone knows how can i fix it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing, checking you've got the latest version and you meet the software's requirements. A printscreen would also help.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down the Alt key and click unity.exe this should let you open or create a new project rather than try loading the one that is crashing.